# Code for folding out a window and folding in all others

Tags: javascript, html, function

The function foldout works perfectly but I want the second function to run first to close all other elements first but I don't know what is wrong; Thank you for helping!

Edit. The second function doesn't seem to work or close already opened forms.

Edit. Thank you all for the answers; I will have more time tomorrow to read and try everything.

functions.js:

```
function foldout(fold) {

    if (document.getElementById) {
        var fold = document.getElementById(fold).style;
            if (fold.display == "block") {
                fold.display = "none";
            } else {
                fold.display= "block";
            }
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
};
function foldall () {
    var foldall = document.getElementsByClassName('foldall');
        for(var i=0; i<foldall.length; i++) {
            var foldthis = foldall[i];
        if (foldthis.display == "block") { 
            foldthis.display = "none";
            }
        }
};
```

page.php:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foldall('foldall'); return foldout('fold');"> </a>
<form method="POST" style="display: none;" class ="foldall" id="fold">
</form
```

Comment: What is happening that is wrong to you? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `foldall` function from your `foldout` function:

```
function foldall () {
    var foldall = document.getElementsByClassName('foldall');
        for(var i=0; i<foldall.length; i++) {
            var foldthis = foldall[i];
        if (foldthis.display == "block") { 
            foldthis.display = "none";
            }
        }
};

function foldout(fold) {
    foldall(); // collapse everything
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var fold = document.getElementById(fold).style;
        if (fold.display == "block") {
            fold.display = "none";
        } else {
            fold.display= "block";
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And call only foldout from your `onclick` handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foldout('fold');"></a>
<form method="POST" style="display: none;" class ="foldall" id="fold"></form>
```